# Using compiled images inside Handlebars erb templates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, handlebars.js, asset-pipeline, production-environment

I am using a couple of `.hbs.erb` templates featuring different icons. Everything works fine in `development`. However, when I push my app to Heroku (production), `<%= image_tag...%>` from Handlebar templates still point to non-compiled image assets , resulting in:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/foobar.svg"):
```

How can I make sure that correct image assets are being served from within my `js` templates?